# NGINX Incorrect Base URL

Tags: nginx

I have the apache sitting on 9000 and then nginx reverse proxying it. Config us below

```
upstream lb_servers {
    least_conn;
        server 127.0.0.1:9000;
        server localhost:9000;
    }

# HTTPS server
#
server {
    listen 443 ssl default deferred;
    server_name domain.name;

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    root /www/;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_pass http://lb_servers;
   }
}
```

The problem is that HTML comes back with the following

```
<head>
<base href="http://lb_servers/" />
...
</head>
```

How do I put domain name in the `href` rather than `http://lb_servers/`?

P.S.
Re question why apache and then nginx, I have migrated a legacy app using docker (apache sits inide docker) having ready nginx ansible scripts  with with letsecrypt setup and etc. I don't want to spend too much time on it anymore.

Comment: Hope it is just an example when you have `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` as load balancer destinations. Otherwise it makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

The `<base href...>` tag is generated by your application running behind Apache. nginx does not alter the output from upstream connections, although you could try using `sub_filter` module for replacing content.

It is best to change the upstream application so that it generates correct content.

Comment: I guess upstream simply uses value of `Host` header

Comment: nginx does change it. checked inside the box & apache spits out `localhost:9000` as base href.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should use [`proxy_set_header`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_set_header) directive.

```
proxy_pass http://lb_servers;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

By default nginx uses value of [`$proxy_host`](http://nginx.org/r/$proxy_host) variable for `Host` header.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be very close! Now I get
```
    <base href="http://my.site/" />
```
But resources cannot be loaded due to CSP, trying to figure out how to make nginx spit out HTTPS.

Comment: I believe this one should be an accepted answer since it does resolve base url issue perfectly